# Plot equation / clustering of a plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Is there any way to get the function or to get only the points in the top of the plot? Consider that the x variable is time (date, seconds) or samples/minute and that the amplitude of the "oscillation" is not fixed. Consider also that the period is not constant.

[image]

I was wondering if there is a built-in function in numpy/matplotlib/pandas libraries. Currently I am finding a math equation that could make it work.

Comment: Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Add data. Have you run FFT analysis? There will be a pretty clear spectral component at the frequency of the envelope.

Comment: That's a peculiar form of noise and could imply mis-processing earlier in the pipeline. It might be fixed by a `(y - 1024) mod 2`.

Comment: A few days ago I posted an answer (I'd say an excellent answer), but I've received zero feedback from you. Do you have solved on your own? do you just don't care anymore? or have you found my solution satisfactory?

Answer (score 0):

one possible workaround using matplotlib is to set the y-axis range.
Try adding:

```
plt.ylim((1024, 1026.01))
```

to that exact plot.

Here's the documentation:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html

Comment: This is not a solution. OP wants to get the function for points at the top, not just display the functions at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I totally understood your issue. But, what about filtering the data points with a threshold? Assuming your data is stored in a list, you could use:

```
filtered_list = [x for x in my_list if x > 1024]
```

Comment: Why should this be stored in a list? The question is tagged `numpy`.

Comment: Do you see any code to be sure that is not? Anyway, it is not relevant for the logic of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if there is a built-in function in numpy/matplotlib/pandas libraries.

Not one that I know of (but my knowledge of Pandas is essentially not-existing). On the other hand, you can do what you want using Scipy.

The blue line in the first subplot below was synthesized by two randomized cosines curves (the orange and the green ones).

The curves in the second subplot were "extracted" from the blue line data (only from the blue line data) using the [`scipy.cluster.vq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.vq.html) module.
[image]